# bash for loops - how to use the ${file} variable?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I would like to run a command on a list of paired files with the following format

```
SAMPLE_1.1.fq.gz SAMPLE_1.2.fq.gz
SAMPLE_2.1.fq.gz SAMPLE_2.2.fq.gz
```

etc...

etc. That are in a directory called ../cleaned-trimmed

I have the list of samples in a txt file (samples_final.txt - one sample per line) in a directory called info.

```
SAMPLE_1
SAMPLE_2
SAMPLE_3
```

I would like to run the following command on all the samples:

```
gsnap <args> --output-file=./alignments.gsnap/SAMPLE_1.mapped.sam --failed-input=./alignments.gsnap/SAMPLE_1.unmapped.fa ../cleaned-trimmed/SAMPLE_1.1.fq.gz ../cleaned-trimmed/SAMPLE_1.2.fq.gz
```

Where the args are the database used, command flags, etc.

I modified the script from a previous answer in stackoverflow to build a loop as follows:

```
for file in $(<../info/samples_final.txt)
do
gsnap <args> --output-file=./alignments.gsnap/${file}.mapped.sam --failed-input=./alignments.gsnap/${file}.unmapped.fa ../cleaned-trimmed/${file}.1.fq.gz ../cleaned-trimmed/${file}.2.fq.gz
done
```

but it does not pass the variables on correctly.

How do I pass on the values from samples_final.txt to the command?
At the moment the script garbles the file names when I run the loop.  So, for example, if I run a test on the file "for_test2.txt":

```
SAMPLE_1
SAMPLE_2
```

Using the echo command:

```
for file in $(<../info/for_test2.txt)
do
   echo ../cleaned-trimmed/${file}.1.fq.gz
done
```

I get the following output:

```
.1.fq.gzed-trimmed/SAMPLE_1
.1.fq.gzed-trimmed/SAMPLE_2
.1.fq.gzed-trimmed/
```

So it seems to have replaced ../clean with the .1.fq.gz

I genuinely do not understand the logic of this.

Comment: Don't use `for file in $(...)`, this is not a way to read a file line by line. [How to read a file line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 1):

You have dos line endings in your file. The "carrier return" character makes the cursor jump to the beginning of the current line, that's why the `.1.fq.gz` part in your last code snipped is printed on the beginning of the line. You can first convert your file to normal line endings:

```
dos2unix ../info/for_test2.txt
```

Then read the file line by line and execute your command. Remember to quote your variables:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
   # protect against empty lines in input file
   if [ -z "$file" ]; then continue; fi

   gsnap <args> --output-file=./alignments.gsnap/"$file".mapped.sam --failed-input=./alignments.gsnap/"$file".unmapped.fa ../cleaned-trimmed/"$file".1.fq.gz ../cleaned-trimmed/"$file".2.fq.gz
done <../info/for_test2.txt
```

or like a pro with `xargs`:

```
<../info/for_test2.txt xargs -I{} gsnap <args> --output-file=./alignments.gsnap/{}.mapped.sam --failed-input=./alignments.gsnap/{}.unmapped.fa ../cleaned-trimmed/{}.1.fq.gz ../cleaned-trimmed/{}.2.fq.gz
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked very well.  I am very much NOT a pro so I appreciate your clarifications.  Would there be a way to use this to pass the processing onto multiple processors in parallel?  I have 24 processors available per core and it would be nice to be able to run these analyses in parallel to save time...

Comment: So `xargs -P 24` will run 24 processes in parallel. See [man xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html). `-t` option is very helpful to debug. And you can add echo to debug it: `xargs   -t -I{} echo gsnap ..... {}  <../info/for_test2.txt`. There is also GNU `parallel` utility, much like `xargs` but more advanced.